# calculate sum from csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have to calculate two parameters (total number or items and total value of all items) from a csv file in python. The question asks us to read the csv file, sort the list by product id and display information by structuring the code in three functions (main function, read_products and print_product_info). the output should look something like:

```
Product ID: 123432
Description: Dell Venue Touchscreen Tablet
Unit Price: $184.99
Inventory Count: 29
Value: $ 5,364.71
```

here is the csv file:

```
Id,Description,Price,Inventory Count
892373,Dell Chromebook 13,449.99,20
432999,Dell Silver Inspiron Laptop,790.00,15
123432,Dell Venue Touchscreen Tablet,184.99,29
563900,Dell Inspiron Desktop,379.00,10
```

Here is what I wrote till now:

```
def read_products(products):
    products_list =[]
    my_file=csv.reader(open('products.csv'),delimiter=',')
    heading = next(my_file)
    ID, Description, Price, Inventory_Count = row
    sort=sorted(my_file, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    for line in sort:
        products_list.append(row)
    return (products_list)

def main():
    total_number_of_items = 0
    total_value_of_all_assets = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Whenever I try to do any calculation in the main function I get an error in the If__name__ line. How can I do calculations in the main function to sum the two parameters? 
Additionally, how can I print the product info separately one by one but in the format above?

Comment: So which is the full error traceback?

Comment: your `read_products()` function is never called from your `main()` entry point. Is that normal ?

Comment: Your code does not raise any errors here.

Comment: That was how my professor taught us. We did write a program in class that worked where the read_products () function was not called from main (_

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you are passing an argument named `products` to the function `read_products` which you're not using inside the function (I guess you meant the file name?). About the `__main__` error, would be useful to have the traceback...

Anyway, have you tried `pandas`? Would make this a lot easier:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_products(filename):
    products = pd.read_csv(filename)
    # Sort by ID, you can use other columns as well
    products.sort_values(by='Id', inplace=True)
    return products

def main(filename):
    products = read_products(filename)
    total_value = products['Price'].sum()
    total_count = products['Inventory Count'].sum()

    print products
    print 'Number of items:', total_count
    print 'Total value:', total_value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('products.csv')
```

If you don't want to/can't use `pandas`, here's another approach with printing function:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

def read_products(filename):
    products = list(csv.reader(open(filename)))
    header = products[0]
    sorted_items = sorted(products[1:], key=itemgetter(0))
    sorted_products = [header] + sorted_items
    # NOTE: This is a list of lists, not a csv.reader instance
    return sorted_products

def print_table(table):
    for row in table[1:]:
        lines = ['{}: {}'.format(table[0][i], v) for i, v in enumerate(row)]
        string = '\n'.join(lines)
        print string, '\n'

def main(filename):
    products = read_products(filename)
    total_value = sum([float(row[2]) for row in products[1:]])
    total_count = sum([int(row[3]) for row in products[1:]])

    print_table(products)
    print '-------------------------------------'
    print 'Number of items:', total_count
    print 'Total value:', total_value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('products.csv')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this with print statement to check. It just runs without any output.

Comment: I tired with with a few  edits:
def read_products(filename):
 my_file=csv.reader(open('products.csv'),delimiter=',')
 heading = next(my_file)
 sort=sorted(my_file, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
 for line in sort:
     return (my_file)


def main(filename):
    products = read_products(filename)
    total_value = int(products['Price'].sum())
    total_count = int(products['Inventory Count'].sum())
    return total_value
    return total_count
    print (total_value)
    print (total_count)

The error now is 'TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: I can't understand much without indentation... From what I understood, in your function `read_products`, you are returning a `_csv.reader` instance  which you are trying to access in `main` as a `pandas.DataFrame` object (again, try `pandas` will make your life easier).
Also, if you call `return` twice in your `main` function, only the first one will be actually returned. I will edit the answer now with how to return the totals.

Comment: Just added similar code without using pandas, in case you can't/don't want to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did do something similar and it worked. :D

Comment: You're welcome. If it works (or not), you should consider accepting and/or voting the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Had a few syntax error which was hard to find. Thanks everyone for the feedback.

```
def read_products(products):
    product_list = []
    with open(products, "r") as f:
        f_csv = csv.reader(f)
        headings = next(f_csv)
        for row in f_csv:
            product_list.append(row)
    return (product_list)


def main():
    products = read_products('products.csv')
    list.sort(products, key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=False)
    total_items = 0
    total_assets = 0
    for row in products:
        print('Product ID:', row[0])
        print('Description:', row[1])
        print('Unit Price:', row[2])
        print('Inventory Count:', row[3])
        print('Value:', (float(row[2]) * float(row[3])))
        print("\n")
        total_items = total_items + float(row[3])
        total_assets = total_assets + (float(row[2]) * float(row[3]))
    print('Total Number of items is', total_items)
    print('Total Value of all assets:', total_assets,end="\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```